# Having trouble activating a NextUI Modal when pressing NextUI Table Row

Tags: typescript, next.js, nextui

I am currently working on a web portfolio using NextJS, TypeScript, and TailwindCSS. I have a page on the site where I am displaying the books that I've read and my ratings using a NextUI table. For reference as to what the table looks like as I describe the problem, you can view it [here](https://www.roshen.dev/book-reviews). When you hover over a row, it is highlighted. My current goal is to add a feature where a Modal of my review of the book appears when you click on a row. I am having some difficulty getting this functionality to work as the following error appears:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
    at $eb2240fc39a57fa5$export$bf788dd355e3a401.getFullNode (import.mjs:219:53)
    at getFullNode.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (import.mjs:282:30)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at [Symbol.iterator] (import.mjs:303:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at visit (import.mjs:717:22)
    at new $788781baa30117fa$export$596e1b2e2cf93690 (import.mjs:719:32)
    at eval (import.mjs:768:165)
    at eval (import.mjs:330:16)
    at updateMemo (react-dom.development.js:12462:5)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:13396:16)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1772:21)
    at $7613b1592d41b092$export$6cd28814d92fa9c9 (import.mjs:324:65)
    at $4a0dd036d492cee4$export$907bcc6c48325fd6 (import.mjs:768:96)
    at useTable (chunk-774VMS2G.mjs:56:84)
    at eval (chunk-MJZDDVZM.mjs:42:68)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:11009:18)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:15665:20)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:18408:16)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:26741:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:25587:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:25303:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:25258:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:24475:20)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24420:26)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:261:34)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:230:14)
    at MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline (scheduler.development.js:534:21)
```

I have been unable to decipher this error or find a workaround for it.

Here is the code the renders each book as a row and the modal that should supposedly appear when the row is clicked:

```
{(item) => {
          return (
            <>
              <TableRow
                key={item.title}
                className='hover:bg-sky-100 hover:dark:bg-gray-950 hover:dark:border-black/40 hover:dark:bg-opacity-30'
                onClick={onOpen}
              >
                <TableCell className="" >
                  {item.title}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-center" >
                  {item.author}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-center" >
                  {item.date_read ? item.date_read.toLocaleDateString() : 'N/A'}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-center">
                  <Rating name="star-rating"
                    value={typeof item.overall_score === 'number' ? item.overall_score : parseFloat(item.overall_score)}
                    precision={.1}
                    readOnly
                    size="large"
                  />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell className="text-center">
                  {item.overall_score}
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
              <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange}>
                <ModalContent>
                  {(onClose) => (
                    <>
                      <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">Modal Title</ModalHeader>
                      <ModalBody>
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Nullam pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis.
                          Pellentesque sit amet hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                          Nullam pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis.
                          Pellentesque sit amet hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                          Magna exercitation reprehenderit magna aute tempor cupidatat consequat elit
                          dolor adipisicing. Mollit dolor eiusmod sunt ex incididunt cillum quis.
                          Velit duis sit officia eiusmod Lorem aliqua enim laboris do dolor eiusmod.
                          Et mollit incididunt nisi consectetur esse laborum eiusmod pariatur
                          proident Lorem eiusmod et. Culpa deserunt nostrud ad veniam.
                        </p>
                      </ModalBody>
                      <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="danger" variant="light" onPress={onClose}>
                          Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button color="primary" onPress={onClose}>
                          Action
                        </Button>
                      </ModalFooter>
                    </>
                  )}
                </ModalContent>
              </Modal>
            </>
          )
        }}
```

If you need more context of the code, you can find the whole file [here](https://github.com/Richrosh3/my_webfolio/blob/review-text/app/book-reviews/book-reviews-table.tsx).

Here are the NextUI docs for the [table](https://nextui.org/docs/components/table#table-props) and [modal](https://nextui.org/docs/components/modal#usage).

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Some extra information:

- react 18
- next 14.0.4
- nextui-org/react 2.2.9

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the shorthand `<>...</>` syntax with the more explicit `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>` to wrap multiple elements. I also moved the `key` prop to the outermost element within the loop to make sure of proper identification of each rendered component.

Here is the modified version.

```
{items.map((item) => (
  <React.Fragment key={item.title}>
    <TableRow
      className='hover:bg-sky-100 hover:dark:bg-gray-950 hover:dark:border-black/40 hover:dark:bg-opacity-30'
      onClick={() => onOpen(item)}
    >
      <TableCell>{item.title}</TableCell>
      <TableCell className="text-center">{item.author}</TableCell>
      <TableCell className="text-center">
        {item.date_read ? item.date_read.toLocaleDateString() : 'N/A'}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className="text-center">
        <Rating
          name="star-rating"
          value={typeof item.overall_score === 'number' ? item.overall_score : parseFloat(item.overall_score)}
          precision={0.1}
          readOnly
          size="large"
        />
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell className="text-center">{item.overall_score}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>

    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} onOpenChange={onOpenChange}>
      <ModalContent>
        {(onClose) => (
          <>
            <ModalHeader className="flex flex-col gap-1">Modal Title</ModalHeader>
            <ModalBody>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis.
                Pellentesque sit amet hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
              </p>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
              <Button color="danger" variant="light" onPress={onClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button color="primary" onPress={onClose}>
                Action
              </Button>
            </ModalFooter>
          </>
        )}
      </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  </React.Fragment>
))}
```

If the error persists, this issues may be with a piece of code in this component. If the problem started after adding a new logic, wrap it in a useEffect. It might also be your dependencies. Maybe update them to the latest versions.

Comment: Thanks for responding! My main issue is I am uncertain as to how to debug this as the above error is the only output I get from console. Would you elaborate on what error you may think is in the code? I copied the code directly from the NextUI example on their Modal page. The only difference being that they used a button and I am attempting to use a TableRow.

Comment: Thank you for the input once again! After some more frustrated deep diving, I found this [comment](https://github.com/adobe/react-spectrum/issues/3502#issuecomment-1242241141) that talks about how TableBody can only have TableRow children. Unfortunately, I will have to think of a new way to display my book reviews.